# How to find an element by data attribute with find() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

**I add a data attribute to an element via jquery `data()` function.**

I want to use find() function to get the element. But obviously, it does not work.

What I want to do is caching the element's parent element and do a lot of things.

Like this:

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var $dataElement = $parent.findByData('whatever');
$parent.xxx().xxx().xxx()....;
```

I don't want this:

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var $dataElement = $("#parent [data-whatever='whatever']");
$parent.xxx().xxx().xxx()....;
//It looks like find the parent twice.
```

Can any function do this?

Comment: what element you can find Mr XXXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I add a data attribute to an element via jquery data() function.*

As you mentioned you are setting the `data` to the element with `data()` method of jQuery. Which doesn't adds any attribute in the DOM. So you can't find it with `.find()` that way because it's in memory*.

Instead you should use `.attr()` method to set the data attribute and then you can read it from the DOM with `.find()` method.

<sup>** don't have proper word for it*</sup>

below is an example of setting the data with `.data()` and trying to find it.

---

```js
$('#parent').find('.two').data('test', 'myTest');

var div = $('#parent').find('.child[data-test="myTest"]').length;

alert(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='child one'></div>
  <div class='child two'></div>
</div>
```

---

below is an example of setting the data with `.attr()` and trying to find it.

---

```js
$('#parent').find('.two').attr('data-test', 'myTest');

var div = $('#parent').find('.child[data-test="myTest"]').length;

alert(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='child one'></div>
  <div class='child two'></div>
</div>
```

---

below is an example as per your comment:

---

```js
$('#parent').find('.two').data('test', 'myTest');

var div = $('#parent').find('.child').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('test') == 'myTest'
}).text();

console.log(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='child one'>One</div>
  <div class='child two'>Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, attr() is working good. But I want to use data attribute because it seem like more efficient.Am I right?

Comment: @JamesYin Well that sort of right approach to use `.data()` but as per your requirement `.attr()` would be right approach. Yet if you want to use then you have to read `data` of the each child in a parent context and get the child which has the data set, which tends to be slow as there will be a greater lookup.

Comment: @JamesYin You can see the third example posted in the answer. You can get the element with the `.data()` set via jQuery.

Comment: It make sense. Maybe I have no reason to insist to use data function to find element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the parent element only when it has data attribute value equals to somevalue, you need to use filter function:

```
$parent.filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('whatever') == "whatever"
});
```

If you want to find child element of parent that has data attribute value equals to somevalue:

```
$parent.find("*").filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('whatever') == "whatever"
});;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the data attribute is adding by data() function. So it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$(child,parent)` way and attribute selector `$('[attribute-name]')` as parameter,

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
var $dataElement = $parent.children().filter(function(){
                       return $(this).data('whatever') !== undefined
                   });
```

---

If you need a function `findByData()`,

```
$.fn.findByData = function(dataAttribute){
    return $(this).children().filter(function(){
        return $(this).data(dataAttribute) !== undefined
    });
}
var $parent = $('#parent')
var $dataElement = $parent.findByData('whatever');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhovpmnr/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, but the data attribute is adding by data() function. So it is not working.

Comment: Updated the DEMO] and answer.

Comment: Yes, it's working good. It's using the same way as Milind Anantwar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parent">
    <p data-whatever='whatever'>Whatever1</p>
    <p data-whatever='whatever'>Whatever2</p>
    <p data-whatever='whereever'>Whereever1</p>
</div>


var $parent = $('#parent');
var $dataElements = $parent.find("*[data-whatever='whatever']");
```

This will return an array of decedent elements inside the "#parent" element having data-whatever='whatever'.

```
$.each($dataElements,function(key,val){
    console.log( $($dataElements[key]).html());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vfjccymh/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a expando properties.